# Java, Parsing String with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was just wondering how to properly parse a string that looks like: `SET X 5'

I need to have `SET` in its own variable, `X` in its own variable, and `5` in its own variables

I tried the following piece of code,

```
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
    //System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println(in.next());
    System.out.println(in.next());
    System.out.println(in.nextInt());
}
```

I was just wondering how I can properly parse each part of the input into its own variable, which I can then use for further purposes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you really got so far as to get the scanner to work but you can't use variables? you have 161 points please ask again this is not asked well you can't mean what it sounds like

Comment: I should have mentioned that the println's are not working either. It throws `Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: @bobby W I believe Dmitry answer will help you. And your problem is less related to parsing, ,that you accomplished by your self. Its related to set values in variable.

Comment: Ohh , Could you let us know for which line its throwing exception. StackTrace will be having that line number

Comment: can i see some more of your code this looks fine other than the if (in.hasNextLine())  i don't really follow that but it might make sence

Comment: try just next next next and see if that works

Comment: @Panther Why do you need the Stacktrace? There is only one line that could cause such kind of Exception? What additional information do you expect to see there?

Comment: @Tom If  you see the string shared in question and code it should be working fine. I suspect he is missing something else and also able to share the information, which we may catch by seeing the track.

Comment: @Panther And why do you ask for something irrelevant (in this case) like the Stacktrace and not for the really used input?

Answer (score 2):

Just save it into some variables:

```
String set = in.next();
String x = in.next();
int five = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: I get this error `Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: @BobbyW are you sure, you're parsing exactly that `String`? Maybe you passed "'SET X 5'". (I mean, used single quotes inside double)